# 400 bad request sending xml payload to WCF REST service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, rest

I know there are a few posts asking about the 400 error, and I believe I've read all of them, but I think the problem I'm facing is different.

**This is my WCF service contract**

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/cust_key/{key}/prod_id/{id}", 
           Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
Stream GetData(string key, string id, string data);
```

**And this is the code that I use to send the request to my rest svc**

```
request.RequestUri = 
     new Uri("http://localhost:3138/v1/cust_key/company1/prod_id/testProductID");
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.HttpMethod = "POST";

string xml = 
         @"<Product><name>dell 400</name><price>400 dollars</price></Product>";

byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
string data = Convert.ToBase64String(message);
response = request.MakeWebRequest(null, data);
```

This gave me 400 bad request error. I've tried to change the xml string to the following two and they also produce 400 error

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
       <![CDATA[<Product><name>dell 400</name><price>400 dollars</price></Product>]]>
</string>
```

or

```
<![CDATA[<Product><name>dell 400</name><price>400 dollars</price></Product>]]>
```

If the payload xml is empty string, then everything is fine and 200 is returned. Can anyone give me a hand?

**Edit:** my web.config section. it comes out of box from the [WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd)

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Comment: Doesn't REST mean, you don't have ANY payload in the request and everything is in the URL????

Comment: @Mithrandir REST doesn't care how you pass the payload.

Comment: @abraham: The REST paradigm doesn't but the WCF does!

Comment: @Mithrandir, then how do you post data to a WCF REST service? WCF REST supports POST, so it has to take request payload.

Comment: I am not totally certain but I believe that the operation expect an object e.g. `Product` instead of 3 strings as parameters.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin, that's possible, but when i change the xml payload to empty string, then the service contract gets called and when i examine the 3 parameters, 2 of them that are passed in through URL show value and the 3rd one is null.

Comment: What does the request payload look like in fiddler? Is there anything odd about it?

Comment: @RichardBlewett, nothing odd in fiddler. it looks like how i put in the request body.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin, I am exposing my end point to somebody that has no knowledge of my data structure, so if i can avoid having my caller construct a product instance, that'd be great.

Comment: @Laguna Nvm my last comment. It could be the content type.. try "text/xml".

Comment: @maxbeaudoin, thx for the "text/xml" suggestion, but this time it didn't help.

Comment: @Laguna Can you try `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` inside WebInvoke? Or try working around other BodyStyles.

Comment: @Laguna Did you try without the base64 encoding?

Comment: hm, tried w/o base64 encoding and other body styles...same 400 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example using the `<string>` element should work.  If you know the schema of the XML that you are recieving, you can do the following:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/cust_key/{key}/prod_id/{id}", 
       Method = "POST",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]  
//Almost exacely the same except String is now Product in the method Parameters
Stream GetData(string key, string id, Product data);

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Prodect
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string price { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the client code from your post and it should work fine.  On the other hand, if you want your web service to dynamically accept different XML that are not well defined data contracts you can use XElement as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/cust_key/{key}/prod_id/{id}", 
       Method = "POST",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]  
//Almost exacely the same except String is now XElement
Stream GetData(string key, string id, XElement data);
```

Comment: Is it possible to go about this without having a Product data contract? the product xml is a simplification of my real business problem. In the real scenario, it's not possible to design a datacontract for the xml payload.

Comment: Yes, your second attempt should work with the `<string ...>` element.  I just tried it on my own test server and it works, so I'm not sure why it's not working for you.  NOTE: I used fiddler for my client.

Comment: I just tried again and still got the 400...how are you testing it?

Comment: I'll just update my solution to allow arbitrary XML instead of a well defined object.

Comment: pls excuse my ignorance, how do you do that? are you using visual studio?

Comment: I tested the code with fiddler2, you can download it here: http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/  If you still run into issues, please update your question with the relevant web.config -- system.serviceModel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7476/discussion-between-dmoses-and-laguna)

Comment: thanks! sorry i didn't see your update when i asked you my last question...when you mentioned 'solution' i was thinking VS solution file lol

Comment: Hi DMoses, I was not able to send messages in chat...i wonder if my company's security setting is blocking it. thank you soooo much for helping me. i'm testing your updated solution.

Comment: WOW this is amazing! the updated solution totally worked for me! THANKS!

Comment: I am facing same issue. I need to use the Product as a data contract. So, I am trying to implement approach #1. what is the right way to send the xmlstring in client call? All three xml formats mentioned in the question, are not working for me.